# Jquery Tooltip Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, widget, tooltip

I am very newby as doing this jquery plugins and I started working on this tooltip plugin:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.fn.simpleMessageTtip = function (options) {
        var settings = {
            'messageTxt': 'The notification frequency has been updated',
        };

        if (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        var getTooltip = function () {
            var tTip =
                '<div class="simple-message-tooltip">' +
                    '<div class="message clearfix">' +
                        '</div>' +
                            '<div class="bubble-pointer-bottom"></div>' +
                                '</div>';
            return tTip;
        };

        $("body").prepend(getTooltip());

        $(this).each(function () {
            var $this = $(this); //the caller of the ttip
            var tip = $('.simple-message-tooltip');
            var tipInner = $('.simple-message-tooltip .message');

            var setTip = function (top, left) {
                var topOffset = tip.height();
                var xTip = (left - 50) + "px";
                var yTip = (top - topOffset - 40) + "px";
                tip.css({ 'top': yTip, 'left': xTip });
            };

            $this.click(function(){
                var offset = $(this).offset(); //Offset returns an object containing the properties top and left.
                var tLeft = offset.left;
                var tTop = offset.top;

                tipInner.html(messageTxt);
                setTip(tTop, tLeft);
            },
                function () {
                    tip.fadeIn("fast");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        tip.fadeOut("fast");
                    }, 1000);
                }

            );    
        });

    };
} (jQuery));
```

By the moment is sort of working (you could say lol) but with some problems. Maybe you please help me to find out why?

This is a tooltip that appears when you click on a radiobutton.

My first problem is that I would like the text inside to be a SETTING that can be changed later in order to make the plugin more maleable...But by the moment the plugin is not bringing me the text =(

Also, It is not bringing the tooltip EXACTLY on top of the radiobutton that the user selects.

If you could help me I will be greatly gracefully!!!

This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vrfsx/9/

THANKS IN ADVANCE ALL!! =)
OrangeJuice.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close to having it working. The only thing you need to change is your `click` handler. The following:

```
$this.click(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset(); //Offset returns an object containing the properties top and left.
    var tLeft = offset.left;
    var tTop = offset.top;

    tipInner.html(messageTxt);
    setTip(tTop, tLeft);
},
function () {
    tip.fadeIn("fast");
    setTimeout(function(){
    tip.fadeOut("fast");
    }, 1000);
});
```

Is incorrect; the first function will never be executed (due to an overload of [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click) with two arguments, the last being an event handler) existing. All you should have to do to correct this is merge the two functions:

```
$this.click(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var tLeft = offset.left;
    var tTop = offset.top;

    tipInner.html(settings.messageTxt);
    setTip(tTop, tLeft);
    tip.fadeIn("fast");
    setTimeout(function() {
        tip.fadeOut("fast");
    }, 1000);
});
```

**Updated code:** http://jsfiddle.net/Bky7F/